# Scrollbar x-axis not appear

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

(SOLVED)

I am currently making an app for showing film titles (a simple movie app).
So I made an Accordion (Bootstrap) that will contain movies that added to Favourites.

This favorites section is intentional would be scrollable (left to right).
So at the .accordion-body in the CSS I added :

```
.accordion-body {
  background-color: var(--primary-bg);
  width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  overflow-x:scroll ;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid var(--primary);
}
```

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j27Ol.jpg)
But the scrollbar does not appear but is scrollable (only if I touch and scroll my laptop screen with a finger). Not with the mouse cursor. So I need help with how to show that scrollbar. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't assign a correct value for overflow-x parameter and you should use one of the below values;

```
overflow-x: visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit;
```

I think your answer could be:

```css
.accordion-body {
  background-color: var(--primary-bg);
  width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid var(--primary);
}
```